# Create UITableViewCell with greater width than its table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that its width is larger than UITableView's one (>1500px), user can scroll horizontally to show the whole cell.

I tried to set the contentSize.width of the table to match my cell's width but when I scroll the table view to the left, and when I reach a point higher than screen width, all information disappear and table become white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the table view inside UIScrollView and set its width to match maximum UITableViewCell width, then set the content width of the UIScrollView to match this width, now I can scroll the table horizontally without any problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to use a UIScrollView inside each UITableViewCell.

Comment: I want the whole table to be scrolled not only a cell, UITableView is sub-class of UIScrollView, when I set the content size the horizontal  scrolling is enabled, but when it reach a point greater than screen width table view becomes white.